# Secure upload of big files to Ubuntu server

Tags: upload, security

I need to allow my users an easy way to create a directory and upload a few files to this directory on my Ubuntu server. I also need this to comply with the following requirements:

- Must use the local users for authentication (would also be nice if it can be just a subset of these)
- Everything uploaded must be uploaded as a specific system user
- It must handle files larger than 2gb
- It must lock the user to only the root directory that is used for upload
- All connections must be secure
- Would be nice if partial uploads can be resumed

My initial thought was to setup an FTP server, but I have had hard time finding an FTP server that can be configured to meet these requirements.

Does anyone have suggestions to either what FTP server software that can be configured to meet my needs or a different approach that would meet my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A secure FTP server is the way to go.

Just try [pure-ftpd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) or [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html) with explicit or implicit SSL encryption for both data and control channels. You can configure both to fulfill all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

ProFTP can do what you are looking for.

See `http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/configuration_full.html` for ProFTPDs config options.

Are you users internal on a lan? If not, can you use a VPN connection for the security?

If not, you can setup FTPS `http://proftpd.open-source-solution.org/docs/howto/TLS.html`